# If I have two sets of data with the same amount of values, what's the best approach to finding out the values in the sets that do not match?

Tags: python, set, comparison

For example, lets say I have these two sets of data:

Set1:
    `Host: 123
Name: Name1
Value:1234
Date: 06/19/2019
School: MIT
Color: Black`

Set2:
    `Host: 123
Name: Name2
Value:1234
Date: 06/19/2019
School: Harvard
Color: Black`

What's the best approach in python to compare these two lists and return back a result like the following:

Result

```
Host 123 in set 1 and set 2 do not match!
Set1-Name: Name1
Set2-Name: Name2
Set1-School: MIT
Set2-School: Harvard
```

Any help would be great, thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

```
set1 = '''
Host: 123
Name: Name1
Value:1234
Date: 06/19/2019
School: MIT
Color: Black'''

set2 = '''
Host: 123
Name: Name2
Value:1234
Date: 06/19/2019
School: Harvard
Color: Black'''

import re

for g1, g2 in zip(re.findall(r'(.*?):\s*(.*?)$', set1, flags=re.M), \
                  re.findall(r'(.*?):\s*(.*?)$', set2, flags=re.M)):
    if g1[1] == g2[1]:
        print('{}: {}'.format(g1[0], g1[1]))
    else:
        print('Set1-{}: {}'.format(g1[0], g1[1]))
        print('Set2-{}: {}'.format(g2[0], g2[1]))
```

Prints:

```
Host: 123
Set1-Name: Name1
Set2-Name: Name2
Value: 1234
Date: 06/19/2019
Set1-School: MIT
Set2-School: Harvard
Color: Black
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the data set and add each value to a list line by line.
This would highlight any differences between the two lists.

After the if statement you could format it however you like so that it is more readable.

```
for x, y in zip(Set1, Set2):
    if x != y:
        print(x, y)
```